# IF statement not being executed

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am trying to execute code if a spot in my String array is equal to a String value I pass in.  I know my array is storing the correct values and the method is obtaining the correct value threw the param (I made sure).  When the param value matches a value in the array, the if statement nevers gets hit.  Below is my code

```
public void checkWordForLetter(String c)
{
    int letterSpotIndex = 0;
    int spotNumber = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < (wordLetters.length); i ++)
    {
        System.out.println(wordLetters[i]);
        if(wordLetters[i].equals(c))
        {
            System.out.println("Letter being looked at in array is:  " + c);
            letterSpot[letterSpotIndex] = spotNumber;
            letterSpotIndex = letterSpotIndex + 1;
            spotNumber = spotNumber + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> if a spot in my String array is equal to a String value I pass in

I believe you want to use `contains` instead of `equals`.

If I misunderstood this statement, and you really want to use equals then perhaps you want to compare using `toLowerCase()` on each side.

It's hard to tell exactly without knowing the array values and received argument.

Comment: Thank you!!! I forgot the value (from a button) is stored as upper case and I was comparing against lower=